# How to use foreign keys migration with database migrations. (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-migration, codeigniter-4

CodeIgniter 4 has a handy solution for migrations and seeders. Without the usage of foreign keys, everything is working perfectly. But when I use foreign keys I get "Unable to add foreign key".

This is because of the order of happenings:

Quick example:

```
table bar
 -------------------
| id | name | fooid |
FOREIGN KEY fooid REFERENCES foo.id

table foo
 ----------
| id | name|
```

So when I now run `php spark migrate` or `php spark migrate:refresh` the foreign key can not be set because the `bar` table is created, but the referenced `foo` table does not exist yet.

Technically I could run a separate function that I run after my migration, but I like the one command of `php spark migrate` and everything is done.

What is the correct way to solve this issue?

This is my create table created code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `bar` (
    `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fooid` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `pk_bar` PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `bar_fooid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY(`fooid`) REFERENCES `foo` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    KEY `fooid` (`fooid`)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `foo` (
    `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `pk_foo` PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

---

##### Addendum

I **think** I find the direction of the issue.
Noticed from the comments, it is correct, the order of creation of the tables is not correct. This can be fixed by changing the timestamps in the filename, so that `foo` gets created before `bar`. But as this is not fixing the issue, I found something else:
This is code I'm using to migrate `bar`:

```php
class Bar extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $fields = [
            'id' => [
                'type' => 'int',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'unsigned' => true,
                'auto_increment' => true,
            ],
            'name' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 255,
                'default' => null,
            ],
            'fooid' => [
                'type' => 'int',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'unsigned' => true,
            ],
        ];
        $this->forge->addField($fields);

        $this->forge->addPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->forge->addKey('fooid');

        $this->forge->addForeignKey('fooid', 'foo', 'id', '', 'SET NULL');

        $this->forge->createTable('bar');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->forge->dropTable('bar');
    }
}
```

This generates a `fooid int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`. The issue is, that `foodid` can not be `null` but the fk sets the value to `null` on delete.

But... the default for `null` of a field is `'null' => true` and even if I add this manually, it is not generating the nullable field.

Comment: You must create the table `foo` first, before you can create another table that references it.

Comment: The table exists before after updating the timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply *rename* your migration timestamp prefixes such that the table creation of `foo` comes before that of `bar`. For example, if the migration file names are as follows:

```sh
app/Database/Migrations/2022-02-16-101819_CreateBarMigration.php
app/Database/Migrations/2022-04-22-101819_CreateFooMigration.php ❌
```

Rename their migration timestamp prefixes in that the referenced table (`foo`) comes first.

```sh
app/Database/Migrations/2022-04-22-101819_CreateBarMigration.php
app/Database/Migrations/2022-02-16-101819_CreateFooMigration.php ✅
```

Lastly, rerun the pending migrations. `php spark migrate`.

---

##### Addendum 1

In reference to your newly edited question description, move the table creation query of `foo` to come **before** that of `bar`. I.e:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `foo` ( ...)

CREATE TABLE `bar` ( ...)
```

---

##### Addendum 2

##### 2022-02-16-101819_CreateFooMigration.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Database\Migrations;

use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;

class CreateFooMigration extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->forge->addField([
            'id'          => [
                'type'           => 'INT',
                'constraint'     => 11,
                'unsigned'       => true,
                'auto_increment' => true,
            ],
            'name'       => [
                'type'       => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '100',
            ]
        ]);
        $this->forge->addKey('id', true);
        $this->forge->createTable('foo');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->forge->dropTable('foo');
    }
}
```

##### 2022-04-22-101819_CreateBarMigration.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Database\Migrations;

use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;

class CreateBarMigration extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->forge->addField([
            'id'          => [
                'type'           => 'INT',
                'constraint'     => 11,
                'unsigned'       => true,
                'auto_increment' => true,
            ],
            'name'       => [
                'type'       => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '100',
            ],
            'foo_id' => [
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint'     => 11,
                'unsigned'       => true,
                'null' => true,
            ],
        ]);
        $this->forge->addKey('id', true);
        $this->forge->addForeignKey('foo_id', 'foo', 'id', 'CASCADE', 'RESTRICT' );
        $this->forge->createTable('bar');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->forge->dropTable('bar');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I like the icons in your answer by the way :) I'm still getting the same error. For reference, I added the `CREATE TABLE` statements to my question. Maybe this helps

Comment: @PeterPan Please, check my edited answer. More specifically, the **addendum** section.

Comment: How can I move the order? As I understood (And indeed this is working) re-ordering the timestamps changes the order of the creation. `foo` exist, when I create `bar` after making this adjustment. But still the error.

Comment: @PeterPan After updating the *migration files' timestamp prefixes*, try confirming that the `migrations` database table **doesn't** have rows with the *`class`* column values `App\Database\Migrations\CreateFooMigration` & `App\Database\Migrations\CreateBarMigration` before running the command `php spark migrate`. In addition, delete the tables `foo` & `bar` **before** running `php spark migrate`

Comment: I can confirm that, as I am using `php spark migrate:refresh`. But even when you remove all tables (including migrations) manually and run `php spark migrate` I end up with the same error.

Comment: Please check my recent update of the initial post

Comment: @PeterPan In the `bar` table creation migration, add `'null' => true,` in the "`fooid`" key value array.

Comment: Is already mentioned, I did that and this does not have any efffect

Comment: @PeterPan Please look at the CodeIgniter 4 migration example demo in my edited answer. More specifically the **Addendum 2** section.